# Issue ASP.Net URL Routing - the route on which I redirect 2nd time is not correct

Tags: asp.net

I am facing an issue in ASP.Net URL Routing. Following is the Global.asax code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Project", "{dealname}/{city}/{projectname}/{projectid}", "~/projectpage.aspx");
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Home", "home/{dealname}/{city}", "~/index1.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary { { "dealname", "property-for-sale" }, { "city", "Ahmedabad" } });
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("ProjectType", "result/{dealtype}/{searchstring}", "~/result.aspx");
    }

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }
```

When I open URL of the site Route "Home" is perfectly working. But when Redirect to the Route "ProjectType" using Response.Redirect, the "home/" portion of the previous URL remains as a result, it remains on the same page and in the URL it's showing /home/result/{dealtype}/{searchstring} instead of /result/{dealtype}/{searchstring}.

Please guide me what is missing or what should be done to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Munjal

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution. Instead of using Response.Redirect(), use Response.RedirectToRoute(). This function is specifically used when implementing URL Routing.

Reference Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992853.aspx

Thanks,
Munjal